# passing information to spring transformer in spring-integration

Tags: spring-integration

I want to implement a custom tranformer, but to be able to pass some attributes to it to act as configuration or instructions to it. I am thinking of something like:

```
<integration:transformer input-channel="AAA" output-channel="BBB" ref="transformerBean">
    <attribute key="a" value="b+3"/>
</integration:transformer>
```

so the transformer will know how to create `a`. I am fine with any other means to pass to the `transformerBean` instructions or hints of how it should behave. Is there such a way to achieve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually you can do almost exactly as you described

```
<integration:transformer input-channel="AAA" output-channel="BBB" ref="transformerBean"/>

<bean id="transformerBean" class="...">
    <property name="a" value="b+3"/>
</bean>
```

Basically you configure your bean and then identify it as a `transformer`.